# Why the delay when receiving data?

Tags: angular, single-page-application

I have an app in Angular 4. I have a big problem with the download of the compiled application in a browser. Use standard Angular/Cli. Compile the application team ng build --prod

Interesting fact. If the browser open the network tab and try to refresh the page F5, the app loads in a fraction of seconds.

Also if you open any other than the network, refresh the page, and then go to the tab network, you can see the line where I get the data from the server, it has the status 'pending'. In the server, absolutely, no problem.

First, I have to AuthGuard was a test where I turned to the server and checked the token but when I changed lokigo and cleaned out the request, that nothing has changed.

Where is possible problem? Asking the help of professionals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not in Angulare, the problem was on the production server. it was necessary to add workers for gunicorn